# cin.ignore; cin.clear; cin.fail

Tags: c++

Нашел пример кода с использованием этих функций, но не понимаю для чего они нужны и как работают

```
double getValue()
 {
while (true) // цикл продолжается до тех пор, пока пользователь не введёт корректное значение
  {
    std::cout << "Enter a double value: ";
    double a;
    std::cin >> a

    if (std::cin.fail()) // если предыдущее извлечение оказалось неудачным,
    {
        std::cin.clear(); // то возвращаем cin в 'обычный' режим работы
        std::cin.ignore(32767,'\n'); // и удаляем значения предыдущего ввода из входного буфера
    }
    else // если всё хорошо, то возвращаем a
        return a;
}
```

}

Comment: [Здесь](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream) можете посмотреть.

Comment: У вас же прямо в коде написано

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потоковые обьекты, такие как `cin` и `cout`, также как и любой другой обьект, имеют определенное состояние. Для  них состояние оценивается установкой определенных бит, `goodbit`(установлен по умолчанию и имеет нулевое значение), `badbit, failbit`.  Если по какой то причине поток "сломался", то установится `badbit`, и программа аварийно завершится. Если была попытка чтения типа, но невозможно читать его из буфера, то устанавливается состояние  `failbit`.

1. `std::cin.fail()` будет означать: да, установлен `failbit`, поэтому
   любая попытка читать дальше, будет безуспешным. `std::cin` будет
   ждать очистки всех установленных битов состояния.
2. Это делается функцией `std::cin.clear`, вызов которого приводит к
   обнулению всех битов состояния, а это и есть `goodbit`. Только после
   этого можем попытаться читать что то другое. Если мы решили, что в
   таком случаи(раз не было там числа) нужно пропустить строку и
   попытаться читать число в новой строке, то мы даем команду
   "игнорировать"(читать, но оставлять в буфере) много символов, пока
   не встретим символ перевода строки.
3. `std::cin.ignore(32767,'\n');` и есть эта команда(вместо `32767`
   может быть любая большая цифра такая, что точно больше, чем
   количество символов до '\n')